# How to set a picture programmatically in a NavBar?

Tags: iphone, xcode, icons, navbar, detailview

I have a detailview with a navigation bar with a back button and a name for the view.
The navigation bar is set programmatically.
The name presented is set like this.

`self.title = NSLocalizedString(name, @"");`

The name depends on the presented view.

Now I would like to also present a small icon on the navigation bar which also is depends on the view.

How do I do that?

Comment: Solved it. The code placed under viewDidLoad             UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:icon
                                                                  style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(action:)];
 self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton;
 [addButton release];

Comment: Yes! I found another way of doing it. Sorry none of the answers did work for me. Now I have a rightBar button with pictures depending of the view.

Comment: o man previously i did not understand that you want navigation bar button...sorry for that, and sorry for late adding solution according to your query ..:)

Comment: Didn´t have to be a button, just a picture in the right end of the bar, but a button did the trick for me.

Comment: yup..in navigation bar you can set button and display image on it..:)

Comment: But you can set picture also...no need to set button..just chk my answer again...:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can **set backGround image to navigationBar** Using this

Put in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"title_bar.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Or you can **set navigation bar image** in any view using

```
UINavigationBar *navBar = [[self navigationController] navigationBar];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"TopBar.png"];
    [navBar setBackgroundImage:image forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Or you can **set a view on your NavigationBar** [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13890062/set-titleview-for-all-navigationcontroller-and-navigationitem/13890354#13890354)

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] addSubview:yourView];
```

or

```
self.navigationItem.titleView = YourView;
```

And **set title** using h

```
self.navigationItem.title = @"Your Title";
```

And you can get navigationBarButton using this

```
-(void)getRightBarBtn
{
    UIButton *Btn =[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

    [Btn setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f,0.0f,68.0f,30.0f)];
    [Btn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"yourImage.png"]]  forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    //[Btn setTitle:@"OK" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    //Btn.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Georgia" size:14];
    [Btn addTarget:self action:@selector(yourBtnPress:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:Btn];
    [self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:addButton];
}
```

**And set simple imageView on navigation Bar**

```
UIImageView *image = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"star.png"]];
UIBarButtonItem *backBarButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:image];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = backBarButton;
```

Comment: self.title or self.navigationItem.title gives the same result and the lines for the image does not work. The bar does not show any picture

Comment: Yes. It did alter the navbar to show icons in a row along the bar but it did only work when using iPhone, not using iPad. But unfortunately it does not suit the case I am working with but nice to know anyhow

Answer (score 0):

Add this code into `viewDidLoad` in your ViewController:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"myIcon.png"];
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
imageView.frame = CGRectMake(5, 2, 100, 39);
[self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:imageView];
```

imageView can also be declared as an instance variable, so you can access it after you've added it (e.g. if you want to remove your icon from your navigationBar at some point).

Comment: If I add imageView as a property it still says Incompatible pointer type assigned to UIImage from UIImageView and regarding the frame it is not found on object of type UIImage

Comment: Yes! I found another way of doing it. Sorry none of the answers did work for me. Now I have a rightBar button with pictures depending of the view.

Answer (score 0):

You need to subclass UINavigationBar. Then in drawRect do something like:

```
[[UIImage imageNamed...] drawInRect:...]
```

and call the super method ofcourse

Answer (score 0):

```
UIButton *homeBtn=[[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 46, 28)];
[homeBtn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"homeBtn.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];    
[homeBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(homeBtnPressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

UIBarButtonItem *navHomeBtn=[[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:homeBtn] autorelease];    
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem=navHomeBtn;   
[homeBtn release];
```