# How to add a custom image to a navigation bar and keep the back method in tact?

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I have the following to add a custom image as a back button. The problem is that it overrides the default navigation controller back method.

How can I correct this?

```
 UIButton *button =  [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"button-back-arrow.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
//[button addTarget:self action:@selector(favouriteButtonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[button setFrame:CGRectMake(280, 25, 40, 29)];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];
```

thanks for any help

Comment: chk my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13488710/how-to-set-a-picture-programmatically-in-a-navbar/13488781#13488781

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add this line and method..

```
[button addTarget:self 
                       action:@selector(BtnBack_Clicked:)
             forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
```

and call this method

```
-(IBAction)BtnBack_Clicked:(id)sender{

    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UIView *btnView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 84, 31)];
UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
btn.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 84, 31);
[btn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourImage.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btn addTarget:self action:@selector(action) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[btnView addSubview:btn];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem   = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:btnView];
[btnView release];
```