# How to add button to navigation controller

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem

Here is my code..I am unable to add a button in my navigation controller.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    UIViewController *viewController1, *viewController2, *viewController3,*viewController4;

    viewController1 = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
    viewController2 = [[DisplayAllImagesController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DisplayAllImagesController" bundle:nil];
    viewController3 = [[EmptyView alloc] initWithNibName:@"EmptyView" bundle:nil];
    viewController4 = [[ListView alloc] initWithNibName:@"ListView" bundle:nil];



    self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    self.tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:viewController2, viewController1, viewController3, viewController4, nil];
    self.tabBarController.title = @"Title";

    self.navController = [[UINavigationController alloc]
                          initWithRootViewController:self.tabBarController];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.navController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

So,please let me know how i can add button to navigation controller...please...

Comment: you want leftbutton are rigth button?

Comment: which button you want to add??i.e.back button, Add button,etc

Comment: @ganesh manoj     rightbutton..

Comment: @ParasJoshi      button for grid view...and reload..

Comment: check my ans http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13488710/how-to-set-a-picture-programmatically-in-a-navbar/13488781#13488781

Answer (score 7, accepted):

just add this bellow code in your `ViewController`'s `viewDidLoad:` method...

```
UIBarButtonItem *btnReload = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemRefresh target:self action:@selector(btnReloadPressed:)];
self.navigationController.topViewController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = btnReload;
btnReload.enabled=TRUE;
btnReload.style=UIBarButtonSystemItemRefresh;
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
UIButton *customButton = [UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50,30)];

UIBarButtonItem *closeButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:customButton];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = closeButton;
```

Answer (score 2):

if you want custom button we can use this

```
UIButton *myButton1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[myButton1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"back.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
myButton1.showsTouchWhenHighlighted = YES;
myButton1.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 3.0, 50,30);

[myButton1 addTarget:self action:@selector(back) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

UIBarButtonItem *rightButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:myButton1];
self.navigationItem. rightBarButtonItem = rightButton;
```

Answer (score 1):

> //create the button and assign the image
>       UIImage *buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"button.png"];
>
> UIButton *rightButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

```
[rightButton setFrame:CGRectMake(280,7,buttonImage.size.width,buttonImage.size.height)];
```

> ```
> [rightButton setBackgroundImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
> rightButton.titleLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12];
> [rightButton setTitle:@"Right" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
>
> // add image view
> [self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:rightButton];
>
> [self.navigationController.navigationBar bringSubviewToFront:rightButton];
>
>
> //create a UIBarButtonItem with the button as a custom view
> UIBarButtonItem *customBarDone = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:rightButton];
> self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = customBarDone;
> [rightButton addTarget:self action:@selector(yourSelector:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
> ```

Comment: this is working code, just assign custom image to the button... and it will for for your own scenario ...

Answer (score 0):

UIButton* btn =[UIButton alloc] init];
....
self.navController.view addsubview:btn];