# Set titleview for all navigationcontroller and navigationitem

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

```
[[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleView:button]
```

I tried to set title view as button for all navigation item using above line of code but it is not working.How can I set title view for all navigation bars in my project by writing small code in appdelegate ?

Comment: do you want to set button as title for navigation bar?

Comment: yes it was possible when I added button to the xib(for single xib) but I don't know how to add it to all by program ?

Comment: where are you putting this line?

Comment: in the app delegate file

Comment: start bounty i will give you solution...i solved it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Customizing the Appearance of a Navigation Bar**

> it is alright to modify the barStyle, tintColor, and translucent
>   properties, but you must never directly change UIView-level properties
>   such as the frame, bounds, alpha, or hidden properties directly.

For more detail you can follow apple doc [UINavigationBar Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationBar_Class/Reference/UINavigationBar.html)

**Edit ->**

I solved your query

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] addSubview:yourView];
```

Other [Navigation Related query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13488710/how-to-set-a-picture-programmatically-in-a-navbar/13488781#13488781)

Answer (score 0):

try this dude...

```
//put whatever object in this view..for example button that you want to put...
UIView* ctrl = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:navController.navigationBar.bounds];
ctrl.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
ctrl.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
[navController.navigationBar addSubview:ctrl];
```

let me know it is working or not!!!!

Happy Coding!!!

Comment: I do not have any access to the navigation controller in app delegate  nor I want.I just want that whenever navigation bar appears in the project then title view automatically set to what I wrote in the app delegate file.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you create a navigation controller in addDelegate and set a title to it,
you have to add the following code to didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method.
Notice that you need to set a root view for the viewController which will the viewController that will be displayed inside the navigationController.

```
  yourViewController *mainVC = [[yourViewController alloc]init];
  UINavigationController *navigationController1 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:mainVC];
  navigationController1.title = @"title";
[window addSubview:navigationController1.view];
```

Comment: I do not want to create any navigation controller in the app delegate file.I just want that whenever navigation bar appears in the project then title view automatically set to what I wrote in the app delegate file.

Answer (score 0):

If you use iOS4, you can override drawRect

```
@implementation UINavigationBar (UINavigationBarCategory)

-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{

    UIImageView *itleImageView = //create object
    [self addSubView:titleImageView];
     //set title view in navigation bar
}
@end
```

iOS 5,

```
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion floatValue] >= 5.0) {
    if ([self.navigationController.navigationBar respondsToSelector:@selector( setBackgroundImage:forBarMetrics:)]){

   UIImageView *itleImageView = //create object
   [self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubView:titleImageView];
    }
}
```

i guess this is a right, as i don't have implemented.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to add a logo in every NavigationController, so I made a subclass of 
`UINavigationController` and used this in the `viewDidLoad`-Method

```
UIImage *logo =[UIImage imageNamed:@"logo"];
CGFloat navWidth = self.navigationBar.frame.size.width;
CGFloat navHeight = self.navigationBar.frame.size.height;

UIImageView *logoView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(navWidth-logo.size.width - 5,
                                                                      (navHeight - logo.size.height) / 2,
                                                                      logo.size.width,
                                                                      logo.size.height)];

logoView.image = logo;

[self.navigationBar addSubview:logoView];
```